# Turn given time in string (04:50:00 according to clients timezone) into UTC time in PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

Let's say the client's timezone is BRT (UTC -3)

```
$time_string = "04:50:00"; //time given by client's timezone
$timezone = "UTC"; //wanted timezone
```

I've been trying to make the php identify the client's timezone (BRT) and convert the `$time_string` from BRT to `$timezone`. Example:

> Time given by client: 04:50:00 BRT
>
> Converted time by php: 07:50:00 UTC

This is what I've tried:

```
$time_string = "04:50:00";
$main_date = strtotime(date("Y")."-".date("m")."-".date("d")." ".$time_string);
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date("H:i:s T", $main_date);
```

But the echoed result is coming like this: 04:50:00 UTC.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you show a default timezone (`date_default_timezone_Get()`) before you change it to UTC?

Comment: It returns 04:50:00 GMT, but the client's time is really BRT (UTC-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code will change your user input time to utc. As I am not sure of your timezone I used sao paulo timezone in the code.

```
$now = '04:50:00';
$timezone = 'America/Sao_Paulo';
echo $now."<br />"; 

$timevalue = new DateTime($now, new DateTimeZone($timezone) );
$timevalue->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$utctime =  $timevalue->format('H:i:s');

echo $utctime;
```

List of available timezone
http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php

Comment: I was hoping for something that would automatically identify the client's timezone, but then I found somewhere that php only gets server time... so thank you, your method works for me, I'll just input manually the client's timezone!